# Jsoup - How to by-pass my (random) 403 HTML error?

Tags: java, html, jsoup, http-status-code-403

I need some help with my use of the Jsoup library.

I launch the following script to scan a page of a website.

**1. If I launch the script every 5 minutes :**

After 4 or more loops (after 20 minutes), I am starting to have the following java error :

"org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetchine URL. Status=403."

And more and more often, until having a 403 every 5 minutes.

If I visit the website with a browser (Chrome or anything else) on the same PC I am launching the script, at this point I also get a 403 on any page of the website :

"403 Forbidden" and "Request forbidden by administrative rules"

If I visit the website with my phone, I don't get the 403. Strange...

**2. If I launch the script every 10 minutes, I am getting the following loop :**

3 or 4 times OK, 2 or 3 times a 403, 3 or 4 times OK, 2 or 3 times a 403, 3 or 4 times OK, 2 or 3 times a 403, ...

**My thoughts, question :**

There is a sort a protection on this website and I don't know how to by-pass it. It's like I am banned after a few time, like "too much request". I am already sending a userAgent or a referrer. I give you the full script even if it is not relevant for me. Maybe I made a mistake in it. The goal of this script is to get the text on the "form3" form. To solve the problem, I have to wait several hours for the 403 to disapear.

Could you please help me to fix this 403 ? I am out of solutions... Maybe it is just a problem with the website, I don't know.

**The script :**

```
try {
    String url = "http://...";
    // Some params
    String[] mesId = {"[id=planning11604]","[id=planning11612]","[id=planning12915]"};
    java.util.Random r = new java.util.Random();
    int Guichet = r.nextInt(3);  
    
    // My Jsoup connection
    Connection.Response resp = Jsoup.connect(url)
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
        .referrer("http://www.google.com")
        .method(Connection.Method.GET)
        .timeout(20000)
        .execute();
    Document responseDocument1 = resp.parse();
    
    // "checked" a checkbox in a form and then submit the form.
    FormElement form1 = (FormElement) responseDocument1.select("form#FormBookingCreate").first();
    Element maCheckbox1 = form1.select("[name=condition]").first();
    maCheckbox1.attr("checked", "checked");
    Document responseDocument2 = form1.submit().cookies(resp.cookies()).post();
    
    // "checked" a radio button in a form and then submit the form.
    FormElement form2 = (FormElement) responseDocument2.select("form#FormBookingCreate").first();
    Element Radio1 = form2.select(mesId[Guichet]).first();
    Radio1.attr("checked", "checked");
    Document responseDocument3 = form2.submit().cookies(resp.cookies()).post();
    
    FormElement form3 = (FormElement) responseDocument3.select("form#FormBookingCreate").first();
    System.out.println("3ème page : "+form3.text());
    Guichet = Guichet+1;
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

Comment: Try using random `userAgent` and random `referrer` the same way as you're using random `mesId`.

Comment: Hello, it was a super idea. I just tried it with a loop a 5 minutes, 6 random userAgent and 2 random referrer. Unfortunately, I still have the 503 after 2 loops.

Comment: It seems like this is not about programming as much as it is about circumventing a site's terms of service.